# React componentsDidUpdate vs SetState callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I run this code I get infinite loop in `componentDidMount`, adding if statement in `(prevState !== this.state)` doesn't help neither.

```
state = {
    purchaseable: false,
    totalPrice: 0
  }

  updatePurchaseState = () => ({
      purchaseable: true
    });

  addIngredientHandler = (type) => {
    const newPrice = totalPrice + 1
    this.setState({
      totalPrice: newPrice
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
    this.updatePurchaseState()
  }
```

But if I execute `updatePurchaseState` in `setState` callback everything works fine:

```
addIngredientHandler = () => {
    let newPrice = newPrice +1
    this.setState(() => ({
      totalPrice: newPrice
    }), () => this.updatePurchaseState());
  }
```

According to React documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate `componentDidUpdate` is preferable way to execute `updatePurchaseState`.

Why `componentDidUpdate` runs into infinite loop but `setState` callback doesn't if both update state and should re-render?
What is the best approach for calling `updatePurchaseState`?

Comment: can you post the entire component class and also what you expect the component to do

Comment: What do you think your `updatePurchaseState` does?

Comment: It’s just a sample code that doesn’t do anything valuable. It is used just to uderstand the general idea of componentDidUpdate.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you update your component's state or props, the component will re-render and invoke `componentDidUpdate`. So both functions `addIngredientHandler` and `updatePurchaseState` will trigger `componentDidUpdate` to be called. In `componentDidUpdate` you try to call `updatePurchaseState` again, causing an infinite loop.

The way to do it correctly is that in `componentDidUpdate`, you have to check if `updatePurchaseState` should be called or not, by comparing current state with previous state:

```
  componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.purchaseable !== prevState.purchaseable) {
      this.updatePurchaseState()
    }
  }
```

Please read the [official document](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating) of React for more details